# why does my php script suddenly stop every 10 minutes or so?

Tags: php

i have set

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

at the top of the script. when it suddenly stops its strange, because the browser still shows the page loading animation, there is no output, and the process disappears, and i KNOW for sure the script didn't finish the work. i have output at any possible way when it stops, but i get no output on the page, the page acts like its still loading. but the process has really already been cut

anyone have an idea why it does this?

Comment: I belive you are not in PHP safe mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to edit PHP.ini to raise timeout limits because it's a long-known fact that on some servers setting settings with PHP will not work.

Comment: i see a couple of different timeout's in the phpini, which one concerns this case? do you know?

Comment: i fixed what i thought was a total separate probelm with some indexing, and after that, the script is running continuously again. i dont really know why, but it seems to be fixed.

Comment: They usually have descriptions commented right on top of the values.